# Autosave the form/model content on route change in angular 4

Tags: angular, angular4-router

In angular 4 application, I am moving from one module to other I want to save my content automatically so I need to identify the change in route.

```
class MyClass {
  constructor(private router: Router) {
    router.events.subscribe((val) => {
        // see also 
        console.log(val instanceof NavigationEnd) 
    });
  }
}
```

I have used this code but this call is incrementing for every visit.
Its similar to Gmail compose how it saves data to draft when I moved from composing screen to other.

Comment: what is the expectation actually? you are subscribing to the events so it will be fired 7 times for a single route each subscription for each router event

Comment: this.sub = router.events.subscribe((val) => {
    // see also 
     if (val instanceof NavigationStart) {
                // Hide loading indicator
                alert('compose');
            }
    
  //  this.memoformatSubmit(false);
    });
I used this one its working now

Comment: ok. Happy that it works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are leaving the subscription open when leaving, so it will increment. You need to unsubscribe:

```ts
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

// ...

sub = new Subscription();

// ...

this.sub = router.events.subscribe((val) => {
    // see also 
    console.log(val instanceof NavigationEnd) 

});

// ...

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.sub.unsubscribe();
}
```