# Angular 4 route monitor or URL change

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ui-router, angularjs-scope

Currently, I'm looking for a solution to monitor the changes in the route (URL).
Instance currently I have a flag which is set to false. When there is a change in the form/Page I will change the flag value to true. If the flag value is true I need to show an alert before changing the screen which is URL. How can I go around with this problem?

**Edit:**  currently I'm able to restrict the route change which is made in the same module but not able to monitor when URL points to another module.

I used this question to monitor the URL :

> [Autosave the form/model content on route change in angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48577164/autosave-the-form-model-content-on-route-change-in-angular-4)

This will just help me in identifying the change in the routing but I will not be able to get back to the same page if the model response in to stay on the same page and I won't be able to retain the values that were previously present on the screen

project layout:

```
++MODULE1
----COMPONENT1 (url: /form/1)
----COMPONENT2 (url: /form/2)
++MODULE2
----COMPONENT2 (url: /inbox/)
----COMPONENT3 (url: /inbox/element)
++MODULE3
----COMPONENT4 (url: /sent)
----COMPONENT5 (url: /sent/element)
++MODULE4
----COMPONENT6 (url: /otherurl)
----COMPONENT7 (url: /childOfotherUrl)
```

From the above layout, I can say that if I'm under `module1` I can restrict the URL according to my needs but when I'm in url `/form/1` and change the screen to `/sent` this is where I'm facing the problem.

Comment: Don't change the URL directly during changes in form flag , when form flag changes only trigger alert and on alert close or ok button trigger change route.

Comment: what if the user fills up a form and from the side nav menu he clicks on other URL and then you lose data and URL will be changes.

Comment: If you want user to fill forms in particular order then you should restrict them, or show them popup and buttons(yes and no )with warning "do you want to go to next page your saved data will be lost".   If user clicks yes then change route on yes click and if user clicks no close popup.

Comment: and how do i do that??

Comment: make a flag for form if all the fields in form is filled then only make it true else false. If user clicks on other links and that variable is false then show popup.

Comment: read the question and try to understand it properly I guess you did not understand my question.